# Recursively printing a pyramid pattern with custom spacing

Tags: python, recursion

I'm successfully printing a recursive pyramid pattern in python, but I want to be able to add custom spacing, and I'm running into errors with the attempts that I've made.

Here is the code I have:

```
def printstack(n, indent = 0):
    if n == 0:
        return 'U'
    else:
        print(' '*(n-1) + 'U '*(indent+1))
        printstack(n-1, indent+1)
```

Example:

```
>>> printstack(3)
   U
  U U
 U U U

>>> printstack(3,1)
  U U 
 U U U 
U U U U

Expected Results

>>> printstack(3,1)
    U
   U U
  U U U
```

Comment: Did you mean to `print('U')` in the base case rather than returning it?

Comment: @pjs that actually causes more issues, at the end of each pyramid, a new row with a singular 'U' is now printed if I don't use a return statement.

Comment: Returning it makes no sense, though, since you don't do anything with return values in your recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code, I think you are looking something like this-

```
>>> def printstack(n, indent=0):
...     if n > 0:
...         printstack(n-1, indent+1)
...         print(' '*indent + 'U '*n)


>>> printstack(3)
  U 
 U U 
U U U 
>>> printstack(3,1)
   U 
  U U 
 U U U 
>>> printstack(3,2)
    U 
   U U 
  U U U
```

Comment: Makes sense now... Thank you!

Comment: Wow, seems a bit unfair to revise this solution to use mine!

Comment: @pjs that was me, sorry but I hadn't read yours and it's a coincidence

Comment: @wim Yeah, it *is* the obvious solution once you realize the `return` accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @pjs, You can check edit history, My original answer was posted before you and that solved the question, revision done by wim looks like making it clean only.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to produce what you say you want, and is a bit simpler as well.  Note that the extraneous `return` has been removed.

```
def printstack(n, indent = 0):
    if n > 0:
        printstack(n-1, indent+1)
        print(' ' * indent + 'U ' * n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def printstack(n, indent = 0,spaces=3):
    if n!=0:
        printstack(n-1, indent+1+spaces/2,spaces )
        print(' '*indent + ('U'+' '*spaces)*n )

printstack(5,6,1)
```

output:

```
      U 
     U U 
    U U U 
   U U U U 
  U U U U U
```

changing spaces:

```
printstack(5,6,3)
```

output

```
          U   
        U   U   
      U   U   U   
    U   U   U   U   
  U   U   U   U   U
```

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what the expected results should look like, the spaces aren't added in between the characters, rather just pushed further from the left side of the screen.